# How to get URL present inside div attribute?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

```
<div data-url="https://latestVersionInfo/android/download/">
1.1.0 <span>Nov 10th, 2020</span>
</div>
```

I tried with this:

```
const ver = await page.$('div#versions-items-list.content div');
const versionUrl = await (await ver.getProperty('data-url')).jsonValue();
```

but its not working.!!
Output String is displayed as "***undefined***"

Comment: Can you console.log the ver? Besides why are you using await twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the option is to use the page.$eval API to exercise some code in context of the page and get this attribute value.

```js
const dataurl = await page.$eval('div#versions-items-list.content div', el => el.getAttribute('data-url'));
console.log("dataurl:", dataurl);
```